# How to setup a quartz.config file in a simple Java application?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

How can I setup a `quartz.config` file in a simple Java application?

I want to create this and reference it in my project so I can configure threads etc.

Thanks

Comment: If your topic is longer than your message text, then you should consider rewriting both ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [Quartz Quick Start Guide](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/quick_start_guide.html) to see what a basic `quartz.properties` file looks like. This file must be placed on your classpath, for Quartz to use it. Example:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = 1
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Full documentation of available properties is available in the [Quartz Configuration Reference](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/configuration/).

Comment: Thanks so I just add this to the build path and im ready to go?!

How can I make sure im calling the right shedule using scedhule factory?


Currently using: scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

Comment: Yes, that's correct. StdSchedulerFactory is the right factory to use because it creates the scheduler based on the contents of a properties file.

Comment: dogbane - I was wondering if you knew if it was possible to have only one thread availble for each job/schedule. But have several threads for all the schedules?? I want to be able to run more than one job at a time but dont want to have two threads created on the same job?? i.e if a job hasnt finished before another starts?

Thanks again. I will post this as a quation if yuo dont know.

Comment: hmm, this is tricky. Would be best to post it as another question.

Comment: Fixed this be keeping 4 threads in the properties file and using: public class AbstractJob extends QuartzJobBean implements StatefulJob { @Override protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException { }

On the actual job itself.